# Identical ListViews display differently - Columns don't stretch on one

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have run into a bizarre problem. I am displaying a `UserControl` within a `UserControl` and at the moment each contains a completely identical `ListView`, as in I copied and pasted it from one to the other. On the parent `UserControl`, the `ListView` displays properly, but on the sub-`UserControl` (whatever it's called), the `ListView` columns refuse to stretch to fit their content. I have no idea why this is happening since the code of both `ListView`s is exactly the same. Both are placed directly on the grid.

[image]

On the top left is the `ListView` from the parent control and on the bottom right is that of the child control. Here is the code for both `ListView`s:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Adventurers}"
              Name="AdvListView"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              Grid.Column="2"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
              Grid.Row="2"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
              BorderThickness="3">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ShowAdvWindowCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=AdvListView, Path=SelectedItem}"
                                    PassEventArgsToCommand="False" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate">
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="StatusTemplate">
                <TextBlock Margin="2,1,1,1" Text="{Binding Status}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" CellTemplate="{StaticResource NameTemplate}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Status" CellTemplate="{StaticResource StatusTemplate}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Why would this work on one and not the other? I'm really at a loss at this point.

**Update:** In the parent `UserControl`, the grid layout is:

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        //Listview here among other controls
</Grid>
```

In the child:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        //Listview here
</Grid>
```

Modifying `Grid.Row`, `Grid.Column`, `RowSpan`, or `ColumnSpan` to be correct doesn't fix the problem.

**Update:** A bit more info that may be relevant: When I try to use Snoop on my program. I get this error:

"BindingFailure was detected - The assembly with display name 'Snoop.XmlSerializers' failed to load in the 'LoadFrom' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Snoop.XmlSerializers, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Snoop has no problem with other programs. I don't know if this is related to the issue at all, but I figured I'd post it anyways.

**Update:** I don't think this would matter, but just to be thorough, here is where the child `UserControl` is created within the parent:

```
<Grid>
    //Other controls
    <UserControl Grid.Column="3"
                Grid.Row="3"
                Visibility="{Binding AdventurerInfoVisibility}">
        <view:AdventurerInfoView />
    </UserControl>
</Grid>
```

At this point I'm completely stumped. I can create a copy of the `ListView` in the parent `UserControl` and have it display properly... but for some reason it doesn't want to behave in the child `UserControl`... I'm open to any ideas and if you need more code I would be more than happy to provide it.

Comment: If they are identical can you post the xaml of the grid control that contains the listviews?

Answer (score 1):

After much tinkering and frustration, I found out what was causing the problem. The child UserControl's Visibility was set to Collapsed by default and was made visible by a button click. When I made it visible by default, the columns stretched properly.

Now I just need to find out how to allow it to start collapsed and still maintain the stretched column width.

Answer (score 0):

I create a deom use your code, and it does not to repeat your problem.

I think maybe your child usercontrol had some TextBlock style, and override your container setting.

Comment: maybe you can use Snoop to watch column width and set from what way.

Comment: Well this certainly is interesting. When I try to use Snoop on my program, this happens: "BindingFailure was detected - The assembly with display name 'Snoop.XmlSerializers' failed to load in the 'LoadFrom' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Snoop.XmlSerializers, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." Snoop works just fine on other programs, though.

Comment: Also, the child UserControl has no styles of its own. All that's in there is the grid and the Listview.

Comment: @JasonD,  you can call invalidMeasure() methord after you set Collapsed by default.